# Auth0 - Device authorization flow include client secret on the device?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, auth0

When you follow this guide https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/device/01-login#refresh-tokens

Once receive your access token and refresh token you can call your API using the access token. At a certain point in the time the device you use has to refresh the tokens, hence using the refresh token API.

The thing which troubles me is that you have to embed the **client secret** on the device ? Isn't this a security flaw ? Can't a attacker read this from the shipped firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shouldn't embed the client secret on the device. You're right that anyone will have access to it. You should use Dynamic Client Registration instead (which is part of the OAuth specification family). Every device will then get its own client ID and secret. Even if someone steals that secret, they will be able to impersonate only the concrete device, not your app in general. You can read an overview of the DCR protocol here: https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-connect-understanding-dcr/ (note that I'm affiliated with Curity), or refer directly to the specification: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7591.